# Scrapy CSV file is in the incorrect format

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

Basicallly I am putting this data I extracted into a csv file but there some problems with the format.

-First only the parts get displayed nothing else is displayed fg. Quantity and Price
-Secondly the column headers seem to repeating down rows.

I would like for the parts, prices, quantity to be displayed down different columns and the headers would be the names. If anyone could just tell me where I can learn to do this that would help a lot!

```
    name = 'digi'
    allowed_domains = ['digikey.com']
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"


    }
    start_urls = ['https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=-1%7C428%2C-8%7C774%2C7%7C1&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=cy621&pageSize=500&pkeyword=cy621']

    def parse(self, response):
        data={}
        parts=response.css('Table#productTable.productTable')
        for part in parts:
            for p in part.css('tbody#lnkPart'):
                yield {
                    'Part': p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').extract(),
                    'Quantity': p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').extract(),
                    'Price': p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param span::text').extract()
                }
```

SETTINGS

```
BOT_NAME = 'website1'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['website1.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'website1.spiders'

#Export as CSV Feed
#FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS: ["parts", "quantity", "price"]
FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = "parts.csv"

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'website1 (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the correct data when you test in Scrapy shell ? It's worth trying out your selectors in scrapy shell before commiting them to a script.

I've not looked in detail into your CSS selectors but there's a lot of for loops for essentially all you need to do is loop over the tr's. So finding a CSS selector that gets you all the rows instead of looping over the whole table and work your way down is probably more efficient.

Update:

Since you asked about the for loop

```
for p in response.css('tbody#lnkPart > tr'):
        
       yield {
                'Part': p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').get(),
                'Quantity': p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get(),
                'Price': p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param span::text').get()
       }
```

Note we only need to loop around the tr's this selects all of them. The get() method only selects the item with the specific tr.

Note you'll need to think about how you'll handle space and none items. Worth think over this part carefully and coming up with a simple way to modify the results.

Updated Code

```
def parse(self, response):

    for p in response.css('tbody#lnkPart > tr'):
    
        if p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get(): 
            quantity = p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get()
            quantity = quantity.strip()
            cleaned_quantity = int(quantity.replace(',',''))
        else:
            quantity = 'No quantity'
     
        if p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param span::text').get():
            price = p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param span::text').get()
            cleaned_price = price.strip()
        else: 
            price = 'No Price'
        yield {
                'Part': p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').get(),
                'Quantity': cleaned_quantity,
                'Price': cleaned_price
                }
```

Comment: I am getting the correct data in the scrappy shell. So i do not need the tbody#InkPart loop I can just go straight to the tr's? I am confused on finding a CSS selector that gets me rows.

Comment: for p in response.css('tbody#lnkPart > tr'): 
 yield {
                    'Part': p.css('td.tr-mfgPartNumber span::text').get(),
                    'Quantity': p.css('td.tr-minQty.ptable-param span.desktop::text').get(),
                    'Price': p.css('td.tr-unitPrice.ptable-param span::text').get()
           }

Is what I mean. You only need to select the tr's. get() only grabs item associated with that specific tr.

Note you'll need to think about how to get rid of the space once you have these items. Worth think how you might approach this.

Comment: So I need to use a CSS selector to change the rows and figure out the empty items or should I use a csvExporter? I am very new to python if you had a link that would help because right now I am looking at this. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: It's choosing a CSS selector that will get you the data you want. Each row has data on price, quantity, price etc,,, for that part. 'tbody#lnkPart' selects the tbody with id lnkPart. css('tbody'lnkPart > tr') gives you a list of every row inside tbody with id=lnkPart. https://data-lessons.github.io/library-webscraping-DEPRECATED/02-csssel/ may help you. So we then can loop over every row. We can grab data within the row like you have written out already 'part': p.css.... etc.  Look at the code I've updated my answer first.

Comment: I seem to have got it working thanks, Now I have a problem its only 6 of the items but thank you!

Comment: See updated code, this should solve your errors with quantity and price. There is too much space and so you need to use the strip function for the string to get rid of the whitespace before yielding. This is what I discussing about dealing with whitespacea and none results.